# Chef node not checking in with the server

Tags: chef, chef-server

I've recently moved my clients from one chef server to another, and now none of my nodes are checking in properly.  I can manually run 'chef-client' successfully, and I do have the `chef-client::default` cookbook defined, yet they will not "check in".

These are Ubuntu 14.04 nodes connecting to a Chef 12 server on Ubuntu 14.04.  The only difference between this server and the old one was that I've also moved to using named environments with specific cookbook versions for our own cookbooks.  I haven't explicitly provided entries for the chef-client cookbook or any others since I'm fine with running the latest versions.

I can manually run `chef-client` without error, but I do not see any logs under `/var/log/chef` so I'm not sure where else to look.  I even went so far as to set the `chef_client::interval` attribute on the environment to `1800`, but still no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the contents of `/var/log/chef/client.log`? Or if the chef-client is running as a daemon at all?

Comment: @Martin - As I mentioned, I do not have any logs under /var/log/chef/, including the client.log.  It seems that boostraping and creating new servers solves this issue, so that's how I'm going to resolve this moving forward.